# Fit two line graphs with different values in the same chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, charts, normalize, linegraph

I have one set of data called Earnings which span from 0-80000, and one called NBPrice which span from 0-200, and would like to fit both in the same chart, but the first range is too high, any way to normalize this so both fit well in the same chart?

This is how it looks so far:
[image: current state]

I am quite clueless on how to solve this, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example:  <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example> with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: For the NBPrice line, use ‘y = 400 * NBPrice)’ and add a secondary axis (as a decoration, it won’t alter the mapping). Search for ‘[ggplot2] secondary axis’ on stack overflow for many examples.